# Как определить что окно запущенного процесса готово?

Tags: linux, bash

У меня есть вот такой шелл-скрипт:

```sh
./librefox "$@" & sleep 1 && \
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
```

Он запускает браузер и через секунду разворачивает окно на полный экран. Секунду приходится ждать, чтобы окно браузера инициализировалось. Но проблема в том, что иногда ему хватает и десятой доли секунды, а иногда может тупить больше пяти.

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы скрипт выпполнялся именно после создания окна, а не ждал наугад?

Comment: `xprop -spy ...` или что-нибудь в этом духе для отлова момента **создания** окна. только про «готовность окна», какой бы смысл вы ни вкладывали в это словосочетание, вам никто, кроме самой программы, создавшей окно, не расскажет.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin ну да, создания. Всё что мне нужно - это развернуть его.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пришлось написать lua-скрипт.

Он следит за появлением новых окон и разворачивает их если они не входят в список исключений и их изначальные размеры больше указанных в настройках.

```lua
local conf = {
  exceptions = {
    "Whisker Menu",
    "qBittorrent",
    "Terminal",
    "SpeedCrunch",
  },
  size = { 650, 450 },
  sleep = 0.5,
}

local sleep = require("socket").sleep

local function execute(command)
  local f = io.popen(command)
  local l = f:read("*a")
  f:close()
  return l
end

local function find_exceptions(text)
  for _, exception in ipairs(conf.exceptions) do
    if string.find(text, exception) then
      return true
    end
  end
  do
    text = execute("xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowgeometry")
    local x, y = string.match(text, "Geometry: (%d+)x(%d+)")
    if tonumber(x) < conf.size[1] or tonumber(y) < conf.size[2] then
      return true
    end
  end
  return false
end

local function count_windows()
  local wmctrl_result = execute("wmctrl -lx")
  local windows_total = 0
  for line in string.gmatch(wmctrl_result, "(.-)\n") do
    if not find_exceptions(line) then
      windows_total = windows_total + 1
    end
  end
  return windows_total
end

while true do
  local first_check = count_windows()
  sleep(conf.sleep)
  local second_check = count_windows()
  if second_check > first_check then
    if not find_exceptions(execute("xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowname")) then
      os.execute("wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz")
    end
  end
end
```